# How to get response body in Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

How to get response when I post request with Guzzle I use `"guzzle/guzzle": "^3.9",`
I post fro some url request and I need response body, but with Guzzle I dont find this is response, where use standard php function `file_get_contents` I have response body. How in Guzzle het response body ?

```
$guzzle = new Client();
$postCell = $guzzle
    ->post($url, [], $addProtectedRangeJson)
    ->addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $arrayAccessTokenClient)
    ->addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
;

$postCell
    ->send()
    ->getBody(true)
;

$contents = (string) $postCell->getBody(); // get body that I post -> my request, not response
$contents = $postCell->getBody()->getContents(); // not find getContents, ask me did you mean to call getContentMd5 
$answer = json_decode($postCell->getResponse()->getBody(), true);

return $answer;
```

Now `$answer`:

```
result = {Guzzle\Http\EntityBody} [7]
readWriteHash = {array} [2]
contentEncoding = false
rewindFunction = null
stream = {resource} resource id='77' type='stream'
size = null
cache = {array} [9]
 wrapper_type = "PHP"
 stream_type = "TEMP"
 mode = "w+b"
 unread_bytes = 0
 seekable = true
 uri = "php://temp"
 is_local = true
 is_readable = true
 is_writable = true
customData = {array} [1]
 default = true
```

I try `$contents = (string) $postCell->getBody();` but have my request, not response, but I need response

```
        $url = 'some_url';
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'=>"Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Authorization: Bearer $arrayAccessTokenClient\r\n",
            'content' => $addProtectedRangeJson
        )
    );
    // Creating the context for the request
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

How to get response body in Guzzle ??

I try http guzzle

```
$headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $arrayAccessTokenClient,
        'Content-type' => 'application/json'
    ];
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client($headers);

    $request = $guzzle
        ->post('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId . ':batchUpdate',
            $addProtectedRange
        );
    $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();

    return $response;
```

But have 401? hot to add header ?

**UPDATE**

```
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $arrayAccessTokenClient,
        'Content-type' => 'application/json'
    ];
    $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = new Request('POST', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId . ':batchUpdate', $headers);
    $response = $guzzle
        ->send($request, $addProtectedRange);

    $answer = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    return $answer;
```

but have

```
  "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\\Client::send() must be an instance of Psr\\Http\\Message\\RequestInterface, instance of Guzzle\\Http\\Message\\Request given, called in /home/ivan/host/aog-code/src/Artel/SiteBundle/Helper/GoogleSpreadSheetHelper.php on line 144 and defined"
```

Comment: Marked as duplicate but don't put the link to the duplicate? Nice one!

Answer (score 8):

I find solution

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $arrayAccessTokenClient,
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
];
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId . ':batchUpdate', $headers);
$response = $guzzle
    ->send($request, ['body' => $addProtectedRangeJson]);

$answer = $response->getBody()->getContents();

return $answer;
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve all the data, you can use casting operator:

```
$contents = (string) $response->getBody();
```

You can also do it with

```
$contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

The difference between the two approaches is that `getContents` returns the remaining contents, so that a second call returns nothing unless you seek the position of the stream with rewind or seek .

```
$stream = $response->getBody();
$contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
$contents = $stream->getContents(); // empty string
$stream->rewind(); // Seek to the beginning
$contents = $stream->getContents(); // returns all the contents
```

Instead, usings PHP's string casting operations, it will reads all the data from the stream from the beginning until the end is reached.

```
$contents = (string) $response->getBody(); // returns all the contents
$contents = (string) $response->getBody(); // returns all the contents
```

Comment: `"guzzle/guzzle": "^3.9"` not have `getContents()` in `$response->getBody()` maybe you mean `guzzlehttp/guzzle` ??

Comment: yes using Guzzlehttp/Guzzle

Comment: how to add header to `Guzzlehttp/Guzzle` ? I uopdate question

Comment: You can check this URl : http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers

Comment: Ok, add header but have `  "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\\Client::send() must be an instance of Psr\\Http\\Message\\RequestInterface, instance of Guzzle\\Http\\Message\\Request given, called in /home/ivan/host/aog-code/src/Artel/SiteBundle/Helper/GoogleSpreadSheetHelper.php on line 144 and defined"
`